SQL Server Express mdf file is 50+gb
I have a SQL Server Express database running on a POS register where the mdf file is 50+gb. When I run select @@version I get:

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0  (Build 15063: )

I'm confused by this as I thought SQL Server Express has an mdf file limit of 10GB. Is there something I'm missing?
SELECT type_desc, physical_name FROM sys.database_files; returns:



type_desc
physical_name




ROWS
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.POS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf


LOG
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.POS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf



I limited the ldf file to about 8GB.

The 10GB file size limit for Express Edition only applies to user databases.
System databases like master, model, and tempdb do not have this restriction.
It's not a great idea to store user data in the master database. I don't know if you're technically breaking the licence agreement, though I suspect you are.
